# synchronized Bank account transaction java method

Tags: java, synchronized

I wrote the following Account class and synchronized transaction method:

```
public class Account{
  private boolean accessFree = true;
  private int balance = 0;

  public Account(int balance){
    this.balance = balance;
  }

  public synchronized void transaction(int amount){
    while(!accesFree || amount>balance){
      try{wait();}
      catch (InterruptedException e){}}
    }
    accessFree = false;
    balance = balance + amount;
    accessFree = true;
    notifyAll();
  }
```

My goal is to make this transaction method be available to only one banker at a time, and also that a banker cant take more money than there is in the account, if he try to take 100USD and there is only 50USD he will have to wait until other banker will deposit money.

After writing this method a question arose.
If this method is **synchronized** why do I need to have the accesFree variable? cause anyway only one can enter this method at a time.. there cant be a situation that two (that share the same Account object) will be in the same method at a time

Comment: You don't need the variable. In fact it makes no sense, since the synchronized keyword guarantees it (a lot better) that only one thread will be running that method at a time.

Comment: so when do I need to use those variables in synchronizing methods?

Comment: You don't, unless you create a very complicated method with different blocks that would depend on whether a thread has completed another block. But that would be just bad design. Or if the `accessFree` were to be manipulated from another method (such as one that freezes the account, but that wouldn't be good design either).

Comment: "if he try to take 100USD and there is only 50USD he will have to wait until other banker will deposit money" - In this case, you are planning on throwing an exception right?

Comment: JamesB - no, I want them to wait until other banker has deposit money...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the accessFree variable, making it synchronized is enough.

And the accessFree implementation is not correct. If a thread is put in wait state, there is no code to call notify, so the thread will sleep for ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
public synchronized void transaction(int amount){
    while(amount>balance){
    balance = balance + amount;
  }
```

This much is enough

And this is even better

```
while(amount>balance){
synchronized(this){
       this.balance+= amount;   
    }
}
```

Sometimes do not have to synchronize a whole method, it is preferable to synchronize only part of a method. Though it doesnot matter in your case but in complex method you should just have a lock on the part of the method that is sensitive to concurrent-modification and allowing other thread to do their work